# Problem with piecewise functions, translational invariance (CNN)

Tags: integration, convolution, piecewise-continuity, invariance

I don't understand how to do this question:

Compute the convolution $(f*g)(x)$ for the functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ defined as,

$f(x)$=\begin{cases}
 0&\text{if}\, x\ < a\\
 \exp(-x)&\text{if}\, a \leq x \
      \
\end{cases}

$g(x)$=\begin{cases}
 1&\text{if} \, \frac{-1}{2} \leq  x \leq \frac{1}{2}\\
 0&\text{otherwise}\
      \
\end{cases}

where $(f*g)(x) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(y)g(x-y)dy$

The answer should be a piecewise function like $f$ and $g$, with a as parameter, like the $f(x)$ function.

The problem I have is that I don't understand how to do the calculations with the intervals given for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. Any help is appreciated :)

Kind regards, Pontus

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You need to break up the integration range so that f(y) has a clear meaning (either $0$ or $e^{-y}$). Then in each integration range you will probably have to break it up into two regions again so that $g(x-y)$ has a clear meaning.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you for the links! I have now made the question alot more readable :)

Comment: @Paul If you have the time, would you mind showing me how to do this with this question? I think my knowledge is a bit too weak to come up with the solution myself. I understand your point but I don't really know how to compute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Can you first of all see that
   $$(f*g)(x) = \int^{\infty}_{a}e^{-y}g(x-y)dy$$
   by the definition of $f$
2. Make things easier by changing variables $x-y = p$. Can you see that
   $$(f*g)(x) = \int^{a-x}_{-\infty}e^{-(x-p)}g(p)dp=e^{-x}\int^{a-x}_{-\infty}e^{p}g(p)dp$$
3. Now we can consider values of $a-x$. If $a-x<-\frac{1}{2}$ what is the $x$ range and the value of $f*g(x)$? If $a-x>\frac{1}{2}$ then
   $$(f*g)(x) =e^{-x}\int^{\frac{1}{2}}_{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{p}dp$$
   which leaves the range $-\frac{1}{2}\le a-x \le \frac{1}{2}$ and
   $$(f*g)(x) =e^{-x}\int^{a-x}_{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{p}dp$$

Comment: Thank you kind sir :=)